# find a degree and splitting field for $x^4-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$

Tags: galois-theory

let $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and let $f=x^4-2$. Find the splitting field, its degree and the basis.

My solution

First I find roots of the polynomial $x_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt[4]{2},\hspace{2mm}x_{3,4}=\pm i \sqrt[4]{2}$ and I notice that the polynomial $f=x^4-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ since neither of the above roots are in $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ hence $x^4-2=min pol_{\mathbb{Q}(i)}\sqrt[4]{2}$

Can I deduce from the above that

$[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2}):\mathbb{Q}(i)]=4$

What will be the $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ basis for $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2})$?

In my book the answer is :

-degree is 4

-basis:$\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3\}$ for $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{2}$

Something here I really do not understand. Please explain what is wrong in my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is true,

notice that if you are extending your field by adding $a$, then you also add all power of $a$.
But not all power of $a$ are linerley independent.Thus,Just take linery independent ones as a basis.

in your case,$a^k$ for $4\leq k$ can be written as linear combination of $1,a^1,a^2,a^3$.Actualy, we expect it to   happen since $Q(i,2^{1/4}):Q(i)]=4$ thus,it is 4 dimensional vector space over $Q(i)$.

Or equivalantly,if you know that degree of minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$,let say it is $n$,then $F(a)$ has a base over $F$  with ${ 1,α,α^2,...α^{n-1} }$.

Comment: @ mesel:This is exactly what I was thinking about, but I got confused, when starting to write down elements of the extension field $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2})=\{a+b\sqrt[4]{2}+c\sqrt[4]{2}^{2}+d\sqrt[4]{2}^{3}|a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}(i)\}$ I just missed the fact that the elements like $\pm\sqrt[4]{2}i$ are also there (as coefficients come from $\mathbb{Q}(i)$). So the basis is then $\{1,\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[4]{2}^{2},\sqrt[4]{2}^{3}\}$.

Comment: The solution is true but the reasoning for the polynomial being irreducible is not.

Answer (score 3):

First, the fact that the roots of a quartic do not lie in a field is not enough to show that the polynomial is irreducible. For example, $(x^2+1)^2$ is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$ but has no roots in $\mathbb{R}$. Another detail is that you have to show it is indeed a splitting field (Which is fairly clear). Look at the tower lemma to understand why the basis given is indeed a basis.