# Does $K = \mathbb Q[X]/(X^4 - 2)$ contain the imaginary unit $i$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $P(X) = X^4 - 2 \in \mathbb Q[X]$.
>
> a) Prove that $P(X)$ is irreducible.
> b) Prove that the field $K = \mathbb Q[X]/(P(X))$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q$ and find a generator of it.
> c) Considering $K$ as a subfield of $\mathbb C$, determine if it contains the
> complex number $i$.
> d) Considering $K$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$, find a basis of $K$.

---

**My solution**

a) We have that $P(X) = (X + \sqrt[4]{2})(X - \sqrt[4]{2})(X^2 + \sqrt 2)$. But
$\sqrt 2 \notin \mathbb Q$ by the usual argument and the same can be said of
$\sqrt[4]{2}$. We conclude that $P(X)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

*My solution to points b),c),d) has been invalidated by a typo in the question.*

**Question**

I think $a)$ is correct. Not sure about $b)$ and $d)$. Regarding $c)$, can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Title and b) : Do you mean $K=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^4-2)$ ?

Comment: For (c), see $K$ as the field ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ (why is this possible?). So, does $K$ contain $i$?

Comment: In a) you are probably expected to use the Eisenstein irreducibility Criterion. What you wrote is probably too informal, though the idea could be made formal.

Comment: @DietrichBurde No, of course not. I'm sure he means $K = {\mathbb Q}[X]/(X^4 - 2)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I had the same doubt, but I've copied the text exactly. I think there's a typo. So if $K = \mathbb Q[X](X^4 -2)$ I have to revise everything again, because the elements of $K$ are $a + bX + cX^2 + dX^3 + (P(X))$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Why doesn't it make sense though? Constants are still polynomials.

Comment: And what are the equivalence classes ? If it makes sense, it is a "trivial" sense. Perhaps this was intended, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ah I see. $a \sim b$ iff $a - b = q \cdot P(x)$, so it's a useless quotient.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Since $\sqrt[4]2$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[4]2] = \mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]2)$. And since $P(X)$ is irreducible and also the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[4]2$, we have that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt[4]2] \cong \mathbb Q[X]/(P(X)) = K$. So $K \cong \mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]2)$. But I don't know how to think of $i$ in $K$. Would $i$ be an element of $K$ that squared gives $-1$?

Comment: I think  with this  new notation, it well  means that  $K$ is the
splitting field of  $X^4-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$, in this case the
answer for the big question is yes $i\in K$

Comment: @rubik Taking (c) literally, it asks to consider $K$ as a field of ${\mathbb C}$, i.e., as ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ and then argue that that subfield of ${\mathbb C}$ does not contain the complex number $i$. Of course, that also implies that $K$ does not contain an element whose square is $-1$ by using the isomorphism between $K$ and ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$.

Comment: @m.idaya No, the splitting field of $x^4-2$ has degree $8$, not $4$. Google this on MSE. It has been answered many times - see e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575060/find-a-degree-and-splitting-field-for-x4-2-over-mathbbqi).

Comment: Dietrich Burde: sorry, I never said that the splitting field  of $X^4-2$ is of
degree  4 over $\Bbb{Q}$, I said that it contains $\Bbb{Q}
(i)$.thanks

Comment: @m.idaya, you **did** say that $K$ is the splitting field of $X^4-2$ over $Q$. Since $K$ has obviously degree $4$ over $Q$, you essentally **did** say that the degree $4$. Dietrich was trying to use the degree as an explanation of why your claim was wrong.

Comment: sorry the notation in the original text has modified, the author
has noted $K$ as $\Bbb{Q}/x^2-2$, and (look at my erst  comment) we say
perhaps the author well say the splitting field of x^2-2 over $\Bbb{Q}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument of a) is incomplete. You proved that $P(X)$ has no root in $\mathbb Q$, and to draw the conclusion it's necessary to add the proof that $P(X)$ has no factor of degree $2$, which is pretty similar to your original argument. In fact, if you know that a monic polynomial $f(X)\in\mathbb Z[X]$ is irreducible iff it's irreducible in $\mathbb Q[X]$, it'll be more plain to check that the image of  $P(X)$ in $\mathbb Z_4[X]$ is irreducible.

For d), seems that you were messing the notion of a generating set of a  ring and that of a  $\mathbb Q$ vector space. In fact it's easy to see we can write any element in $K$ as a $\mathbb Q$ linear combination of $1,\bar X,\bar X^2,\bar X^3$ ($\bar X$ is the image of $X$ in $K$) and the four elements are $\mathbb Q$ linearly independent,thus form a basis and the $\mathbb Q$ dimension of $K$ is $4$.

For b), call a field extension $E/F$ finite if $E$ is a finite dimensional $F$ vector space (in case you don't know, $E$ is always a vector space over $F$, so the main concern lies in the dimension, not being a vector space). It's not hard to prove that finite field extensions are always algebraic.

For c), define a morphism $\tilde i:\mathbb Q[X]\to\mathbb R, X\mapsto\sqrt[4] 2$, it's routine to check that $\ker\tilde i\supseteq(P)$, thus $\tilde i$ induces $i: K\to\mathbb R$. But a ring morphism between two fields must be injective, thus we can regard $K$ as a subring of $\mathbb R$. Since $-1$ has no square root in $\mathbb R$, neither does it in the subring $K$.

Comment: The argument of a) is not correct; not having a root does not imply irreducibility.

Comment: @Servaes corrected it, thank you.

Comment: @rubik I think you are right.

Answer (score 2):

For a); not having a root does not imply irreducibility. For example, $X^4+2X^2+1$ has no real roots, but it is certainly reducible. In stead consider using Eisenstein's criterion.

For b); it is not true that $\alpha=q+(P(X))$ for some $q\in\Bbb{Q}$. In stead, $\alpha=Q(X)+(P(X))$ for some $Q(X)\in\Bbb{Q}[X]$. If you have seen enough theory, you might say that because $K$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$, the consecutive powers $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots$ cannot be linearly independent. A nontrivial relation between them yields a polynomial of which $\alpha$ is a root.

For c); there is more than one way to consider $K$ as a subfield of $\Bbb{C}$. One is a real embedding given by mapping $X$ to $\sqrt[4]{2}$. Then $K$ does not contain $i$ because $\Bbb{R}$ does not contain $i$.

For d); the argument for b) show that your argument here fails. Give it some more thought after having understood the previous questions, I think you can figure this one out now.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that there are two misunderstandings. The first is, that you showed  $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=1$. This would imply that $K$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, and hence does not contain $i$. More probably, however, is that the field $K$ is not $K = \mathbb Q/(X^4 - 2)$, but rather $K = \mathbb Q[x]/(X^4 - 2)$. Then we can work with the quotient. Because of Eisenstein, $x^4-2$ is irreducible, so that the ideal $(x^4-2)$ is maximal, and we have that the quotient is a field. Clearly we have $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4$ then, with $K=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$. This is a real field, not containing $i$. It has the basis $1,a,a^2,a^3$ with $a=2^{1/4}$.

Comment: I don't see how you can argue $K$ is real, isn't it possible that we take $K = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2}i)$?

Comment: I can argue that because $K=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$ is  a real field. I suppose you want to know why the quotient is isomorphic to this field, and not to some other field. The splitting field of $x^4-2$ has degree $8$, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575060/find-a-degree-and-splitting-field-for-x4-2-over-mathbbqi).